# How to represent XYZ axes in a graph with javascript?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, plot, geometry

I have a series of data, distributed over time, with three values: XYZ axes. I try to represent the movement of an object with these values, on a graph in javascript.

What type of graph is best to represent the movement? Is there a JS library for it?

Answer (score 1):

Exits a lot of libs of charts in javascript..

you can use:

- http://www.highcharts.com/
- http://www.chartjs.org/
- http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/
- http://www.jqplot.com/

you'll find how to use each in documentation

Comment: But I need to know what type of chart can represent the movement of an object in the time

Comment: you want 3 values (x,y and time ) or 4 values (x, y, z and time) ? if you want 3 you can see this http://www.grvisualisation.50webs.com/javascript_surface_plot.html is a surface chart. for 4 i don't know any chart to help you

Comment: Sorry, I have 4 values, x, y,z, and a datetime.

Comment: your're welcome, if you can use the surface chart share the result if possible, yet to see a working example.

Answer (score 1):

http://bl.ocks.org/supereggbert/aff58196188816576af0 is also a working example.  We needed to visualize spectrum data over time and the Z axis was useful.  Example shows sine/cosine waves.